# Where to stay in Isla de Coiba (Coiba Island)

Tags: camping, nature-and-wildlife, islands, panama

I'm visiting Panama next month and I'd like to visit Coiba Island. I've read that there are no lodges there (except [ANAM ranger station](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Coiba_National_Marine_Park#Sleep)), but I'm wondering if it's possible to sleep at the Island using our own gears (tent, food, water...) In fact, the same page states:

> To get a good impression of Coiba, you should plan to stay there for
>   at least two days

so I suposse that this option should exist. In the case you can camp, you must pay anything? (I've read that there is a $20 fee for entrance, but I don't know if you pay it once or every day).

Note that some people stays overland in Santa Catalina, but I prefer to stay in the Island.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answer myself. After some extensive researching, I've found [this blog post](http://blogdepanama.com/conoce-todo-lo-que-debes-saber-de-coiba-el-paraiso-en-panama/) in Spanish that says:

> The visitor center has some confortable huts with beds, bathroom and
>   AC [..] is the only place you can stay overnight, because you cannot
>   camp.

Also, it explains that there are crocodiles in the area, so it's not a good idea to camp in the beach even if it's allowed. They don't explain if the fee is payable once or you have to pay it every day, but I **suppose** you have to pay only once because this post explains every option with a good budget detail and don't talks about paying a daily fee. The bad part with the post is that prices are outdated, so take these prices as reference, but expect to pay a bit more.